# Как задать аттрибут из связанной таблицы в столбце GridView Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, gridview

Есть 2 таблицы Товары и Инструкции - связаны один-к-одному (так надо было - товар б/у-шный) - каждому товару соответствует одна инструкция. Есть таблица Товары (выводится в GridView) - там выводятся параметры - цена, название, магазин где товар в наличии и пр. но нужно сделать колонку с типом подключения 110В / 220В / 380В - но этот параметр в связанной таблице - Инструкция. Как добавить колонку - напряжение в параметр attribute. Еще хотелось бы добавить колонку - дата выпуска - с DatePickerом - он тоже в таблице - Инструкция.

```
[
    'format' => 'raw',
    'label' => 'Тип напряжения',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        $manual = $model->manual;
        if(!empty($manual->voltage)) {
            return $manual->voltage
        }
        return '';
    },
],
```

Answer (score 0):

В модели Product нужно создать переменную для показа доп поля

```
public $voltage;

 public function attributeLabels()
{
   return [
       ....
       'voltage' => Yii::t('app', 'Voltage'),
       ....
   ],
}
```

В GridView:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'voltage',
    'value' => function($model) {
        return $model->manual->voltage;
    }
],
```

Если связи правильно настроены так заработает (`->manual->` - это название связи в модели Product) без валидации по полю, чтобы работала валидация - вам сюда https://p0vidl0.info/yii2-sortirovka-i-filtr-gridview-po-svyazannym-i-vychislyaemym-polyam.html